# Countability / uncountability of finite, countably infinite languages and their set over finite and countably infinite alphabet

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to understand whether different languages are countable or not.
I can classify the languages on several parameters:

1. Nature of language:

   - Finite language `FL`
   - Countably infinite language `CIFL`
   - Language without any restriction `L`
   - Set of finite languages `SFL`
   - Set of countably finite languages `SCIFL`
   - Set of languages (without any restrictions) `SL`
2. Nature of alphabet: finite `F`, countably infinite `CIF`
3. Countability status of language: countable `C`, uncountable `UC`

Based on these factors, I prepared following table, just to have some overview:

```
    Nature of Language      Alphabet nature       Countability status
1.        FL                       F                      C
2.        FL                       CIF                    C
3.        SFL                      F                      C
4.        SFL                      CIF                    C
5.        CIFL                     F                      C
6.        CIFL                     CIF                    C
7.        SCIFL                    F                      UC
8.        SCIFL                    CIF                    UC
9.        L                        F                      C
10.       L                        CIF                    ?
11.       SL                       F                      UC
12.       SL                       CIF                    UC
```

You may read Point 8 as "set of countably infinite languages `SCIFL` (languages with countably infinite `CIF` number of strings) over countably infinite alphabet is uncountable `UC`." and similarly other points.

Proof of some of above points:

- Points 1 and 3 have been proved [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/42011/49261)
- Points 9 and 11 have been proved [here](https://diego.assencio.com/?index=c51c5ab87e0ee7e7a5cbfafb04f2ba4b)

**Doubts / Questions**

1. I guess points 1,2,5,6 are quite trivial. Those languages themselves have finite `FL` and countably infinite `CIFL` in their names. So, I guess they are already known to be countable and we dont need to put any efforts to determine that they are countable. Right?
2. I feel point 7 can be proved on exact lines of proof for point 11, right?
3. I feel point 8 is uncountable as point 7 which is less stricter (as it involves finite alphabet) variation is uncountable.
4. What is status of point 10, is it countable or uncountable? (Uncountable as specified in doubt 7 below?)
5. I feel point 12 is uncountable as point 11 which is less stricter (as it involves finite alphabet) variation is uncountable.
6. If a set of languages is countable, then does the individual language of that set has to be countable?
7. Despite I have shown some of the languages (points 2,4 and 6) over countably infinite alphabet to be countable in above table, somehow I also feel that any language over countably infinite alphabet is uncountable (mostly because we cannot give proof as for point 9). Is it so? (Does [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/53188/49261) makes all languages in points 2,6 and 10 countable? If yes, what about language in point 4?)
8. I guess, all above languages contain finite length strings. I have completely ignored languages containing infinite length strings. I guess all languages containing infinite length strings over non-singleton alphabet (alphabet not containing single symbol) are uncountable. Am I right? (It seems I am correct according to [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/53190/49261))
9. Did I miss any language in above table?